# Snap browsers don't open pdf

Tags: firefox, snap, chromium, pdf, xdg-open

I use chromium and firefox on kinetic, both don't open PDFs with system handler properly. If chromium is allowed to show PDFs, then firefox opens PDFs i a chromium window. If chromium is not allowed to show PDFs nothing happens. It's looks like xdg-open has some issue with snap sandbox, so it can't pass the open request to evince. How to fix it?